# Request becomes very slow after 100 rapid requests sent HTTPClient C#

Tags: c#, http, tcp, httpclient

I send many requests to different hosts with HTTPClient (C#, .NET Core 3.1).

When my code reach 100-200 requests sent, next requests starts to be very slow.

I tried both ways to work with HTTPClient - static and create new every each request. I was testing HTTPClient disposing too.
I tested request with one Task and more.

I set to every request **ConnectionLeaseTimeout** on 1,2,3,10 seconds.
i was try add **Timeout** to client and **ConnectTimeout** to `SocketsHttpHandler`.
I added disposing Resoponse.

My current code:

```
static async Task<string> Request(string domain)
{
    string result = null;
    string url = $"http://{domain}/";

    var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(url));
    sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 3 * 1000;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
    try
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is OperationCanceledException || ex is TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
    finally
    {
        response.Dispose();
    }

    return result;

}

static void Test()
{
    SocketsHttpHandler socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
    {
        ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
    };
    HttpClient = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);
    LoadDomains("Domains.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {

        if (Domains.Count != 0)
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                ActiveThreads++;
                while (Domains.Count != 0)
                {
                    await Request(Domains.Dequeue());
                    CheckedDomains++;
                }

                ActiveThreads--;
            });

    }
}

static HttpClient HttpClient;
```

I also noticed that the sockets are not reused.

**@UPDATE**
I see now that something helped me.
i noticed that whetether i loaded 200 or 500 or 1000 urls, every time it's becomes very slow after 90% requests. Last 10% are very slow.

Next problem is when i set `Client.DefaultProxy`, then every request becomes slow.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure it's not the server slowing down? Aside: you should use `TryDequeue` as your current dequeuing is subject to race conditions. You should put `HttpResponseMessage` in a `using` instead of `try/finally`

Comment: Does setting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=net-5.0#System_Net_ServicePointManager_DefaultConnectionLimit to 200 help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple HTTP requests trigger HTTP Client timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60013771/multiple-http-requests-trigger-http-client-timeout)

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run`? Also be aware that `ActiveThreads++;` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Charlieface I tested 2 servers, i dont think so.I updated as per the advice, but it's not help.

Comment: @mjwills setting DefaultConnectionLimit to 200 doesn't help

Comment: @mjwills
Ealier i was using Threads, but i had the same problem, then i changed to Tasks.
Should i just lock ```Active Threads++;```?

Comment: _I tested 2 servers_ Well, imo __every__ reasonable server should protect itself from being hammered..

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `HttpClient` for multiple requests. Use `HttpClientFactory` instead of `HttpClient`.

> There are a few problem of HttpClient.
>
> For example:
>
> 1. HttpClient is disposable: Using HttpClient with the using statement is not the best choice because even when you dispose
>    HttpClient object, the underlying socket is not immediately released
>    and can cause a serious issue named ‘sockets exhaustion’.
> 2. HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient
>    class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available
>    under heavy loads. That issue will result in SocketException errors.
>    Possible approaches to solve that problem are based on the creation of
>    the HttpClient object as singleton or static.
> 3. HttpClient that you can have when you use it as singleton or static object. In this case, a singleton or static HttpClient doesn't
>    respect DNS changes.
>
> To address those mentioned issues and make the management of
> HttpClient instances easier, .NET Core 2.1 introduced a new
> **HttpClientFactory**.
>
> What is HttpClientFactory:
>
> 1. Provide a central location for naming and configuring logical HttpClient objects. For example, you may configure a client (Service
>    Agent) that's pre-configured to access a specific microservice.
> 2. Codify the concept of outgoing middleware via delegating handlers in HttpClient and implementing Polly-based middleware to take
>    advantage of Polly’s policies for resiliency.
> 3. HttpClient already has the concept of delegating handlers that could be linked together for outgoing HTTP requests. You register HTTP
>    clients into the factory and you can use a Polly handler to use Polly
>    policies for Retry, CircuitBreakers, and so on.
> 4. Manage the lifetime of HttpClientMessageHandlers to avoid the mentioned problems/issues that can occur when managing HttpClient
>    lifetimes yourself.

**Original answer is this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113671/8810311**

Comment: I saw this answer, but i didn't sure how to implement this.
I will check it again.